# AngularJs: unable to type in between input fields

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie of angularjs using version 1.6.4. I am able to type as usual but unable to put cursor in between to edit the text from the middle while using mobile. In desktop everything works fine.

First try, no luck:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" ng-model="model.user.name">
```

Than i use md-input but still no luck:

```
<md-input-container>
   <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" ng-model="model.user.name">
</md-input-container>
```

I am unable to predict why its behaving like this.

App.js:

```
var module = angular.module(__appName, [
    "ui.router",
    "ngMap",
    "ngFileUpload",
    "geolocation",
    "angular-jwt",
    "angular-storage",
    "jkAngularRatingStars",
    "ui.bootstrap",
    "angularMoment",
    "benharold.haversine",
    "ngMaterial",
    "ngAnimate",
    "toastr",
    "ngTagsInput",
    "angular-click-outside",
    "cp.ng.fix-image-orientation"
]);
```

index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-jk-rating-stars/dist/jk-rating-stars.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/app.css">


<!-- tail -->
<script src="bower_components/exif-js/exif.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ngmap/build/scripts/ng-map.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key="></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-file-upload/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angularjs-geolocation/dist/angularjs-geolocation.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/a0-angular-storage/dist/angular-storage.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-jk-rating-stars/dist/jk-rating-stars.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/moment/min/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-moment/angular-moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-haversine/angular-haversine.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-toastr/dist/angular-toastr.tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/ng-tags-input/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-click-outside/clickoutside.directive.js"></script>

    <script src="bower_components/angular-fix-image-orientation/angular-fix-image-orientation.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using both Bootstrap and Angular Material? Try removing **all** CSS as well as class from the `<input />` and see if the field works on mobile then.

Comment: I removed both Bootstrap.min.css and angular-material.min.css but still couldn't write in between

Comment: Try using the `input:text` at the following sample [Angular application](https://plnkr.co/edit/K8olK1EzJGFatRXYAwEN?p=preview) on mobile. If your keyboard does not activate on mobile when focusing on the input, there is an entirely different issue going on. Also in your application do you have any errors in the console when loading the application?

Comment: "ngMaterial" module is making trouble, when i removed it, fields start to work fine. But i used md-input which comes from angular material than why fields are not working properly.

Comment: Okay please provide your `angular.module()` code where you are registering the third party modules of your application to help determine the issue. Also provide how you are adding the `angular-material.js` to your applicaton.

Comment: I've updated the post